# Can not play recorded audio file from android in iOS 5+

Tags: android, ios5, avaudiorecorder, aac, android-mediarecorder

I am working on android app which also supports iOS. I want to record the audio & play it in Android as well as in iOS devices.  I am recording audio in android using following settings

```
MediaRecorder audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
audioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
audioRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
audioRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12800);
audioRecorder.setOutputFile(<recordedSoundFilePath>);
audioRecorder.prepare();
audioRecorder.start();
```

On iOS side , settings are as follows

```
//audioRecorder is object of  AVAudioRecorder 

NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    NSNumber *formatObject;
    formatObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC ];

    [recordSettings setObject:formatObject forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self soundFilePath]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

    if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] == YES){
        [audioRecorder record];
    }else {
        int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig ([error code]);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ [%4.4s])" , [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode);

    }
```

I can record the audio & it is playing correctly in android devices.
Now the problem is I can play the recorded audio from iOS in Android device , but **iOS device  can't play the audio recorded on Android device**. It returns `OSStatus error 1937337955`. I searched about this error , but I can't find anything.

Can anybody tell me what's going wrong in my code ?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PrvN: is it solved? i also have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But we want AAC AudioEncoder. I tried changing AudioSource to Default from MIC , but it doesn't help.

Comment: where u playing the record file i mean in app?? or sdcard file through   player in mobile??

Comment: File can be played in Android app and player also,but not playing ios side.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in which audio that recorded from Samsung's device is not working on all IOS devices and not even on safari browser. But they working fine in all android devices. I have fixed this issue by adding below lines in AudioRecordingUtil class:

```js
recorder?.let{
  it.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
  it.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS)
  it.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
}
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

It is codec issue , the format recorded by iOS is not able decode by android media player , in order to make it work just decode the audio file on IOS side in to android supported format like mp3 or mp4 or 3Gp etc.

Comment: I also agree with you(Android_Craker) .I already faced such kind of issue, and the only solution is to generate the audio file in android supported format i.e., mp3 ,mp4 ,3gp, wav etc.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered issues with MediaRecorder. At the time of Audio Record, Mime Types are different like

```
Mac chrome - Mime Type:audio/webm;codecs=opus
Mac Safari - Mime Type:audio/mp4
Windows/Android - Mime Type:audio/webm;codecs=opus
Iphone Chrome - Mime Type:audio/mp4
```

I was saving the file as M4a but Audio was not running in IOS. After some analysis and Testing. I decided to convert the file after Upload in Server and used ffmpeg and It worked like a charm.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/ffmpeg-platform -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2-1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>


 /**
 * Convert the file into MP4 using H264 Codac in order to make it work in IOS Mobile Device
 * @param file
 * @param outputFile
 */
private void convertToM4A(File file, File outputFile) {
    try {
        String ffmpeg = Loader.load(org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class);
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpeg, "-i", file.getPath(), "-vcodec", "h264", outputFile.getPath());
        pb.inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    }catch (Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```